# Which Micrometer metric is better to count database values found?

Tags: database, spring-boot, micrometer

We want to implement a Grafana dashboard that shows in how many calls to a database a value is found
I´m not sure which Micrometer metric to use:

[Counter](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_counters): Counters report a single metric, a count.

[Timer](https://micrometer.io/docs/concepts#_timers): Measures the frequency

According to that, I would choose the counter, because I just want to know how many times we find a value in the database.

Comment: You want a gauge.

Comment: checketts from de oficial docs: "Gauges are useful for monitoring things with natural upper bounds. We don’t recommend using a gauge to monitor things like request count, as they can grow without bound for the duration of an application instance’s life.". The number of values found can grow without upper bound.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the information you hope to capture based on the metric. You most likely want a gauge.

You aren't timing anything so a Timer wouldn't be a good fit.

**Counter** - is used for measuring values that *only go up* and can be used to calculate rates. For instance, counting requests.

**Gauge** - is used for measuring values that go up and down. For instance, CPU usage.

If you are counting values in a database result, that number could go up and down (if that table allows deletion). However, if the amount only goes up, using a counter would make sense, and give you the ability to see the growth rate, but that will only work if you can guarantee the number is only going up.

Comment: Hi checketts, thanks for answering. I want to count if a value is found in a database and when it is not. 

e.g.: dataRepository.findById(Id).

Comment: So valid values would be 1 or 0 and it can go up or down?

Comment: It can go up (maybe thousands). We want to know how many values are found, and how many not.

Comment: And that count can go down, too, right? Also keep in mind that you want to query to be quick so it doesn't slow down metric collection. You might consider running the query in a separate thread on a schedule and saving it to a variable that the gauge is looking at, instead of running the query in the gauge itself.